# Pandas - Update Columns Conditionally with np.where()

Tags: python, pandas, vectorization

I am trying to make a trading backtester in Pandas and having some issues with 'if' statements using np.where() to update other columns conditionally.

My initial df, where signal indicates whether to buy/sell or neither (1/-1/0), based on these signals I want to update the Cash, Hold, Value and Total columns.

```
                        open         high        low        close   change  signal  Cash  Hold Value Total 
time                                        
2017-09-09 03:01:00 4255.000000 4256.799805 4233.600098 4252.799805 -0.000065   0   10000.0 0.0 0.0 10000.0
2017-09-09 03:02:00 4251.399902 4258.500000 4247.500000 4258.399902 0.002046    1   10000.0 0.0 0.0 10000.0
2017-09-09 03:03:00 4256.500000 4289.299805 4256.500000 4273.700195 0.001262    1   10000.0 0.0 0.0 10000.0
2017-09-09 03:04:00 4273.100098 4299.899902 4262.580566 4284.100098 0.001905    1   10000.0 0.0 0.0 10000.0
2017-09-09 03:05:00 4291.200195 4299.799805 4284.200195 4289.899902 -0.000854   -1  10000.0 0.0 0.0 10000.0
2017-09-09 03:06:00 4295.000000 4298.799805 4279.500000 4279.500000 -0.000047   0   10000.0 0.0 0.0 10000.0
2017-09-09 03:07:00 4278.000000 4278.299805 4277.000000 4277.799805 -0.000244   0   10000.0 0.0 0.0 10000.0
```

I can do this by manually calling each of the below functions based on the signal:

```
def buy_update(i=i):
    pf['Cash'].iloc[i] = pf['Cash'].iloc[i-1] - trade_size
    pf['Holdings'].iloc[i] = pf['Holdings'].iloc[i-1] + (trade_size / pf['close'].iloc[i])
    pf['Holdings Value'].iloc[i] = pf['close'].iloc[i] * pf['Holdings'].iloc[i] # Update Values
    pf['Total Holding'].iloc[i] = pf['Cash'].iloc[i] + pf['Holdings Value'].iloc[i] # Update Values

def sell_update(i=i):
    pf['Cash'].iloc[i] = (pf['Cash'].iloc[i-1] + (pf['Holdings'].iloc[i-1] * pf['close'].iloc[i])) # get cash for sale
    pf['Holdings'].iloc[i] = 0 # Sell down all assets
    pf['Holdings Value'].iloc[i] = pf['close'].iloc[i] * pf['Holdings'].iloc[i] # Update Values
    pf['Total Holding'].iloc[i] = pf['Cash'].iloc[i] + pf['Holdings Value'].iloc[i] # Update Value

def no_action(i=i):
    pf['Cash'].iloc[i] = pf['Cash'].iloc[i-1]
    pf['Holdings'].iloc[i] = pf['Holdings'].iloc[i-1]
    pf['Holdings Value'].iloc[i] = pf['close'].iloc[i] * pf['Holdings'].iloc[i] # Update Values
    pf['Total Holding'].iloc[i] = pf['Cash'].iloc[i] + pf['Holdings Value'].iloc[i] # Update Values
```

Which then produces this:

```
                        open         high        low        close   change  signal  Cash        Hold       Value      Total 
time                                                        
2017-09-09 03:01:00 4255.000000 4256.799805 4233.600098 4252.799805 -0.000065   0   10000.00000 0.000000    0.000000    10000.000000
2017-09-09 03:02:00 4251.399902 4258.500000 4247.500000 4258.399902 0.002046    1   9900.00000  0.023483    100.000000  10000.000000
2017-09-09 03:03:00 4256.500000 4289.299805 4256.500000 4273.700195 0.001262    1   9800.00000  0.046882    200.359297  10000.359297
2017-09-09 03:04:00 4273.100098 4299.899902 4262.580566 4284.100098 0.001905    1   9700.00000  0.070224    300.846864  10000.846864
2017-09-09 03:05:00 4291.200195 4299.799805 4284.200195 4289.899902 -0.000854   -1  10001.25415 0.000000    0.000000    10001.254150
2017-09-09 03:06:00 4295.000000 4298.799805 4279.500000 4279.500000 -0.000047   0   10001.25415 0.000000    0.000000    10001.254150
2017-09-09 03:07:00 4278.000000 4278.299805 4277.000000 4277.799805 -0.000244   0   10001.25415 0.000000    0.000000    10001.254150
```

I thought that a nested np.where() would work to call the correct function based on the signal column but I am not having any luck. The below loops over each row.

```
for i in range(len(pf)):
    np.where(pf['signal'].iloc[i] == -1, sell_update(i), np.where(pf['signal'].iloc[i] == 1, buy_update(i), no_action(i)))
    print(i)
```

I think it currently calls every function - sell, then buy, then none (each overwriting the last) as well as produce a `SettingWithCopyWarning` warning.

Also the for loop over each row is obviously incredibly slow, is there a way to vectorize this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the calculation code becomes complex, it's difficult to vectorize it. Since process element by element in pandas is slow, you can convert the dataframe to a list of dict, and do the calculation, here is an example that use `cytoolz`:

```
import io
import pandas as pd

text="""time                        open         high        low        close   change  signal  Cash  Hold Value Total 
2017-09-09 03:01:00 4255.000000 4256.799805 4233.600098 4252.799805 -0.000065   0   10000.0 0.0 0.0 10000.0
2017-09-09 03:02:00 4251.399902 4258.500000 4247.500000 4258.399902 0.002046    1   10000.0 0.0 0.0 10000.0
2017-09-09 03:03:00 4256.500000 4289.299805 4256.500000 4273.700195 0.001262    1   10000.0 0.0 0.0 10000.0
2017-09-09 03:04:00 4273.100098 4299.899902 4262.580566 4284.100098 0.001905    1   10000.0 0.0 0.0 10000.0
2017-09-09 03:05:00 4291.200195 4299.799805 4284.200195 4289.899902 -0.000854   -1  10000.0 0.0 0.0 10000.0
2017-09-09 03:06:00 4295.000000 4298.799805 4279.500000 4279.500000 -0.000047   0   10000.0 0.0 0.0 10000.0
2017-09-09 03:07:00 4278.000000 4278.299805 4277.000000 4277.799805 -0.000244   0   10000.0 0.0 0.0 10000.0"""
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(text), delim_whitespace=True)
trade_size = 100

import cytoolz

def f(p, c):
    change = c["signal"]   
    if change == 0:
        cash = c["Cash"]
        hold = c["Hold"]        
    elif change == 1:
        cash = p["Cash"] - trade_size
        hold = p["Hold"] + trade_size / c["close"]
    elif change == -1:
        cash = p["Cash"] + p["Hold"] * c["close"]
        hold = 0
    return cytoolz.merge(c, {"Cash":cash, "Hold":hold})

pd.DataFrame(list(cytoolz.accumulate(f, df.to_dict("records"))))
```

Comment: Thanks, that is blazingly quick in comparison! I'm still wrapping my head around what is exactly happening. Why does (p,c) work for current and previous values?
I also added more and want to return other columns like `return cytoolz.merge(c, {"Cash":cash, "Holdings":hold, "Holdings Value":holdings_value, "Total Holding":total_holding})` and it results in an error `local variable 'holdings_value' referenced before assignment`. Any idea why that might be?

Comment: you need to set `total_holding` and `holding_value` variable in the `if elif`

Comment: Yeah I did, snippet below. Should I make a new question?
`def f(p, c):
    change = c["signal"]   
    if change == 0:
        cash = p["Cash"]
        hold = p["Holdings"] 
        holdings_value = p["Holdings Value"]
        total_holding = p["Total Holding"]`